# Is there any way in SQL or function in MYSQL that sums up all the increments in a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find a way to sum up all the increments in the value of a column.

We provide delivery services to our customers. A customer can pay as he go, but if he pays an upfront fee, he gets a better deal. There is a table that has the balance of the customer across the time. So I want to sum all the increments to the balance. I can't change the way the payment is recorded.

I have alredy coded an stored procedure that works, but is kind slow, so I'm looking for alternatives. I think that, maybe, an sql statement that can do this task, can outperform my stored procedure that has loops.

My stored procedure makes a select of the customer in a given date range, and insert the result in a temp table X. After that, it starts to pop rows from X table, comparing the balance value in that row against the previous row, and detects if there is an increment. If there is not increment, pops another row and do the same routine, if there is an increment, it calculates the difference between that row and the previous, and the result is inserted in another temp table Y.

When there are no rows left, the stored procedure performs a SUM in the temp table Y, and thus, you can know how much the customer has "refilled" its balance.

This is an example of the table X, and the expected result:

```
DATE        BALANCE
----        -------
2019-02-01  200
2019-02-02  195    //from 200 to 195 there is a decrement, so it doesn't matter
2019-02-03  180
2019-02-04  150
2019-02-05  175    //there is an increment from 150 to 175, it's 25 that must be inserted in the temp table
2019-02-06  140
2019-02-07  180    //there is another increment, from 140 to 180, it's 40
```

So the resulting temp table Y must be something like this:

```
REFILL
------
25
40
```

The expected result is 65. My stored procedure returns this value, but as I said, is kind slow (it takes about 22 seconds to process 3900 rows, equivalent to 3 days, aprox), I think is because the loops. I would like to explore another alternatives. Because some details that I don't mention here, for a single costumer, I can have 1300 rows per day (the example is given in days, but I have rows by the minute). My tables are indexed, I think properly. I can't post my stored procedure, but it works as described (I know that "The devil is in the detail"). So any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using 5.7.26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a user-defined variable to hold the balance from the previous row, and then subtract it from the current row's balance.

```
SELECT SUM(refill) AS total_refill
FROM (
  SELECT GREATEST(0, balance - @prev_balance) AS refill, @prev_balance := balance
  FROM (
    SELECT balance
    FROM tableX
    ORDER BY date) AS t
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prev_balance := NULL) AS ars
) AS t
```

Comment: "The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined." (from the documentation dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html), so this is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: Thanks, I was away on weekend, but I will post my results. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Hi @Barmar. First, sorry for the delay, I was assigned to another project and recently I returned to the previous project. I did give a try to your solution, and the performance was notably better. I'm aware that some SELECT's in my stored procedure that were the cause of the time the stored procedure take to process.  So, using your solution taked down the execution time by 10X. I compared the results and they were the same consistently. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a quite well-known mechanism to deal with these: Use a variable inside a field.

```
SELECT @result:=0;
SELECT @lastbalance:=9999999999; -- whatever value is sure to be highe than any real balance
SELECT SUM(increments) AS total FROM (
  SELECT
    IF(balance>@lastbalance, balance-@lastbalance, 0) AS increments,
    @lastbalance:=balance AS ignore
  FROM X -- insert real table name here
  WHERE
    -- insert selector here
  ORDER BY
    -- insert real chronological sorter here
) AS baseview;
```

Comment: . . I thought it was well known that "The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined."  (from the documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html and true in earlier versions as well), so this method is explicitly documented as *not being guaranteed to work*.

Comment: The order of evaluation is indeed undefined, in contrast to the order of evaluation vs. assignment, which is well-defined: The assignment will happen **after** the evaluations. This means, that the value of `ignore` is to be ... ignored.

Comment: I will try with your suggestion too. Like  many of people, I don't like to use something hardcoded. But if it works, it is simple, and covers all the use cases I can face, then I'm ready to use it!

Comment: I tried with the first solution in this post, and it worked! It's similar to yours. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()` in MySQL 8+:

```
select sum(balance - prev_balance) as refills
from (select t.*, lag(balance) over (order by date) prev_balance
      from t
     ) t
where balance > prev_balance;
```

In older versions of MySQL this is tricky.  If the values are continuous dates, then a simple `JOIN` works:

```
select sum(t.balance - tprev.balance) as refills
from t join
     t tprev
     on tprev.date = t.date - 1
where t.balance > tprev.balance;
```

This may not be the case.  Then the next best method is variables.  But you have to be very careful.  MySQL does not declare the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`.  As the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) explains:

> The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined. For example, there is no guarantee that SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1 evaluates @a first and then performs the assignment.

The variables need to be assigned *and* used in the same expression:

```
select sum(balance - prev_balance) as refills
from (select t.*,
             (case when (@temp_prevb := @prevb) = NULL  -- intentionally false
                   then -1 
                   when (@prevb := balance) 
                   then @temp_prevb
              end) as prev_balance
      from (select t.* from t order by date) t cross join
           (select @prevb := NULL) params
     ) t
where balance > prev_balance;
```

And the final method is a correlated subquery:

```
select sum(balance - prev_balance) as refills
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.balance
              from t t2
              where t2.date < t.date
              order by t2.date desc
             ) as prev_balance
      from t
     ) t
where balance > prev_balance;
```

Comment: Wow, quite explanatory. I will give a shot and keep you posted.

Comment: I tried with the @Barmar solution that is like yours. I couldnt try with MySql 8+, because I have 5.7.26  Besides, the dates aren't incremental by day, they increment normally by the minute, but not always. The last solution you suggested ressemble the solution I used by Barmar advice. Thank you!